# Calling Javascript on a loaded site

Tags: c#, javascript

How would I call a function in Javascript on a loaded site in a Windows Form Application web browser? For those that have used Chrome, I'm looking to call Javascript like you can with the Javascript console.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Java or javascript? Because Chrome does indeed have a console for javascript.

Comment: Edit'd, was referring to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser;
        wb.Navigate( ... link or Uri ...)

        object[] args = new object[1];
        args[0] = 12';
        wb.Document.InvokeScript("functionName", args);
```

InvokeScript runs javascript functions. if you have a javascript function like function check(value)`{...}` than your functionName is "check" and your args array hold value, if you have more parameters you can fill your args as much as parameters you want. The code above runs the javascript function as functionName(12);

If you want to access any element you can use this code:

wb.Document.GetElementById("ControlId")
       .InnerText = "Bla bla" 
       .InvokeMember("click")